# How to display the user picture on the search page?

Tags: 7, theming, users, search

I want to show the user picture on the search page. Currently only its show the user email or name, but I want to show the user profile picture.

How can I do that?

**Note**: the search page is about the user type, so when I search some users their picture should be displayed on the search result page.

Comment: Not able to understand which type of content you searching on search page

Comment: user type when i am search some user its picture should be display on search result page

Comment: http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/adding-images-search-results go through this article hope so it may help you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the file `YOUR_SITE/modules/search/search-result.tpl.php` to your theme and modify the code inside with this:

```
<?php
//obtaining the username
$username = explode('(', $title);
$username = trim($username[0]);
//getting the user object
$user = user_load_by_name($username);
?>
<li class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>

  <?php 
  /*
   * The following line will print the user picture
   */
  print theme('user_picture', array('account' =>$user));
  ?>

  <h3 class="title"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
    <a href="<?php print $url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
  </h3>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
  <div class="search-snippet-info">
    <?php if ($snippet): ?>
      <p class="search-snippet"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>><?php print $snippet; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($info): ?>
      <p class="search-info"><?php print $info; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</li>
```

This will be the output:

[image]

**EDIT:** If you want follow another way you can read this: [How to access to the user info on the search page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/187055/28275)

Comment: if we show user first name or last name field then how can i do that

Comment: Which order of fields you want?

Comment: Like our other field city name or may be country name

Comment: @AdeelNawaz I can't understand what are you trying to do, post another question with more information please. And let me know

Comment: check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187171/how-to-display-the-user-registration-or-profile-field-on-the-search-page