# How to access to the user info on the search page?

Tags: 7, users, search

When I was trying to resolve this question: [How to display the user picture on the search page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/186901/28275) I found that in the THEME_preprocess_search_result function I can't access to the user information (I use the user search functionality) the only information about the searched users that I can use is the follow:

```
function THEME_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
    dpm($variables);
}
```

[image]

I can use the username and the email, I can extract from $variables['result']['title'] the username, but I think that the best way is access directly to the uid of the searched user. The problem is that I don't know how access to this information.

So, there is another way to obtain the uid of a searched user?

**EDIT:** I need the info of the system users (drupal users). User is not a content type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try implementing `hook_preprocess_search_results` (notice the plural search results)?

I haven't tested recently and I'm on a mobile right now. But I'm pretty sure that hook somehow had node objects (should be user objects in your case). Collect the UIDs, run a `user_load_multiple` and then add the user objects to each result for profit in `hook_preprocess_search_results`.

**Update**

I'm no longer on my mobile, so I could actually test this. It turns out that the `user` module does not feed the results set with the user account. I don't think Drupal 7 will receive these features anymore, so you'd have to patch the core `user.module` to achieve that.

Here is a patch if you are interested in going down that path: https://gist.github.com/Ayesh/b1892942b053dc746fb5

Comment: is the same situation, there is not info about the users (drupal users). User is not a content type in my case they are the system users.

Comment: thanks, I think that you must post the patch at drupal.org

Comment: Can I post the patch at drupal.org?

Comment: Sure! But I believe that odds are that this will not get into D7 core because it's too late for us to add new features. But feel free to!

Comment: the patch is for wich version 7.41 or 7-dev?

Comment: It should apply for both, because the search module did not get any new patches that I'm aware of or could find yet.

Comment: but the patch is for the user module

Comment: Sorry, yes the patch is for the user module. But still, I don't think the patch wouldn't apply for the latest dev. It wouldn't be too hard to reroll the patch if it does not apply either.