# How to display the user registration or profile field on the search page?

Tags: 7, theming, users, search

How can I render/display user profile or registration field on search result page (user search)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the template file `YOUR_SITE/modules/search/search-result.tpl.php` to your theme and modify the code inside with this:

```
<?php
//obtaining the username
$username = explode('(', $title);
$username = trim($username[0]);
//getting the user object
$user = user_load_by_name($username);
?>
<li class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <h3 class="title"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
    <a href="<?php print $url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
  </h3>
  <p>
  <?php 
  /*
   * The following lines will print the info
   */
  print $user->field_date_of_birth[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] . "<br>";
  print $user->field_gender[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] . "<br>";
  print $user->field_your_industry[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] . "<br>";
  print $user->field_your_city[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] . "<br>";
  print $user->field_zip_code[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] . "<br>";
  print $user->field_countrynew[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] . "<br>";
  ?>
  </p>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
  <div class="search-snippet-info">
    <?php if ($snippet): ?>
      <p class="search-snippet"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>><?php print $snippet; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($info): ?>
      <p class="search-info"><?php print $info; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</li>
```